# Develop a script to pull data from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, jupyter-notebook, google-api-python-client

I'm working on developing a Python script to pull data from Google Analytics. I'm using the code in their [document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py).

I also tried Postman and Core Reporting API, and they are working

I'm getting this error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
cell_name in async-def-wrapper()

cell_name in main()

<ipython-input-17-81b765f9722c> in get_service(api_name, api_version, scopes, key_file_location)
     13 
     14     credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
---> 15             key_file_location, scopes=scopes)
     16 
     17     # Build the service object.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py in from_json_keyfile_name(cls, filename, scopes, token_uri, revoke_uri)
    218         """
    219         with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
--> 220             client_credentials = json.load(file_obj)
    221         return cls._from_parsed_json_keyfile(client_credentials, scopes,
    222                                              token_uri=token_uri,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 296         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297 
    298 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Try using google query explorer to make curl calls https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/